# visual studio outlining doesn't work with asp.net inline code

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have a website project, that uses C# inline code for ASP.NET pages and controls.

Code outlining doesn't work with asp.net inline code.

Any idea why? Any way to fix that?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the following menu command?

**Edit > Outlining > Start Automatic Outlining**

Comment: its turned on, as u can see left to the script tag, but not working for code inside script tag